# How to extend Angular Form Directive to have globally autocomplete="off"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

As we know in Angular `<form>` is a directive. I'm wondering if there is any way to extend that directive.

I need this because I want to append attribute `autocomplete="off"` always when I use `<form>` on my view. Or maybe there is another, easier way to set it globally?

Comment: I don't think such feature is built in `@angular/forms`, but you can create a custom directive which will apply the `autocomplete` attribute using `@HostBinding('attr.autocomplete') v ='off';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular diretive selector can also be select by css.As @Andrei Gatej mentioned in the comment you can use hostbinding to bind autocomplete attribute to all input inside form like this:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type="text"]'
})
export class FormDirective {
  @HostBinding('attr.autocomplete') autoComplete ='off'; 
  constructor() { 
  }

}
```

Comment: AFAIK we can't use nested selector. `form input[type="text"]` is an equivalent of `input[type="text"]` Btw why just not use `form` selector?

Comment: ohh you're right, so easy. Thanks :) 
Btw. `selector: 'form'` is enough, since inputs inherit from forms that autocomplete behavior.

Comment: I thought It' would work netsed seclor Thanks for the correction @yurzui.

Answer (score 0):

you should write own directive. Here is docs https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives